2000ish movie about a traveller looks like Daniel Auteuil
French movie, 2000s, I think it might be with Daniel Auteuil, but going through his filmography didn't ring a bell.
There's a guy who is moving through a lot of places in the city and there's an important soccer game going on so everyone is thrilled (people watch in a bar, his friend is trying to watch bits at home).
There's a scene with some crazy woman who is falling in love with the main character and some weird line about her hamster. She wants them to die together cause she thinks it's romantic. Can someone give me the name of this one?

Gregoire Moulin vs. Humanity from 2001.

Grégoire Moulin, a shy accountant, sets up a blind date with a dance teacher at a bar. What he needed to do was just to cross the road. But it didn't happen to be as easy as it seems, especially because of the final game of French soccer championship the very same night!

It stars Artus de Penguern, which I guess slightly resembles Auteuil. And during his wild journey throughout the city, he comes across a suicidal woman that talks to hamsters. Here's the trailer:



